# How to configure StdinReader to only show workspaces?

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I have a very simple xmonad/xmobar configuration, with this on the left hand side of xmobar:

`[1] 2 : Tall : How to configure StdinReader to only ...`

How can I remove the layout name and window title? (`Tall` and `How to ...`) ??

I can see the template in `xmobarrc2` looks like this:

```
template = "%StdinReader%}{<fc=#FFF>%date%</fc>"
```

So it looks like `StdinReader` provides all 3 of those items, but how can I configure this? I can't seem to find anything useful about this, except maybe `UnsafeStdinReader`, but I really don't get how it works, or how I'm supposed to go about researching this..

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My entire `xmobarrc2`:

```
    Config { font = "xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=16:antialias=true:hinting=true"
            , borderColor = "black"
            , border = TopB
            , bgColor = "black"
            , fgColor = "grey"
            , position = TopP 0 0
            , commands = [ 
                      Run Weather "CYVR" ["-t","<tempC>C","-L","18","-H","25","--normal","green","--high","red","--low","lightblue"] 36000
                    , Run Network "eth0" ["-L","0","-H","32","--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
                    , Run Network "eth1" ["-L","0","-H","32","--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
                    , Run Cpu ["-L","3","-H","50","--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
                    , Run Memory ["-t","Mem: <usedratio>%"] 10
                    , Run Swap [] 10
                    , Run Com "uname" ["-s","-r"] "" 36000
                    , Run Date "%a %_d.%_m  %H:%M" "date" 10
                    , Run StdinReader
                            ]
            , sepChar = "%"
            , alignSep = "}{"
            , template = "%StdinReader%}{<fc=#FFF>%date%</fc>"
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of commands defined in your `xmobarrc2` (Weather, Network, Cpu, Memory, Swap, Com, StdinReader and Date) but the only ones you actually use in your `template` are StdinReader and Date (you could delete the others if you wanted to). Now, while Date works (and is formatted) as defined above, StdinReader just reproduces the (pre-formatted) output of XMonad. Therefore, the place to change what you want to have changed is in your `xmonad.hs`.

XMonad uses logHooks to report on internal state updates such as window titles, focus changes etc. Such a logHook is typically used to pipe those informations into a status bar. [XMonad.Hooks.StatusBarPP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Hooks-StatusBar-PP.html) implements a logHook defining a pretty-printer (PP) to format the content to be output. This module also defines `xmobarPP` which additinally implements some specific features such as setting the colors in a way XMobar expects them (`<fc=#FFF>…</fc>`), etc. Thus, with XMobar, you typically install a logHook using `xmobarPP`.

These pretty-printers allow the user to customize the formatting using specific functions. One of them is

```hs
ppOrder :: [String] -> [String]
```

which by default is called with a list of strings being (in this order) the workspaces, the layout, the current window title, and anything you have defined using another function called `ppExtras`. To only have the workspaces, redefine it as:

```hs
ppOrder = \(ws:_) -> [ws]
```

Summing up, your `xmonad.hs` will need something along the lines of:

```hs
main = do
  -- ...
  xmproc2 <- spawnPipe "xmobar path/to/your/xmobarrc2"
  -- ...
  xmonad $ ewmh desktopConfig
    { 
      -- ...
      , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
          { 
            -- ...
            , ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc2
            , ppExtras = []
            , ppOrder = \(ws:_) -> [ws]
            -- ...
          }
      -- ...
    }
  -- ...
```

Comment: Thanks pmf. Where are you getting all this information? for example, how would I find out about `[ws]` or `\(ws:_)`? My xmonad.hs looks so different to what you posted, I am going to have to play around with it and figure out how it maps to yours

Comment: XMonad is written and configured in [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)). To find information on how it works, you need to look up the modules that are being used (internally or as imports in your `xmonad.hs` configuration file), just like I suggested with [XMonad.Hooks.StatusBarPP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Hooks-StatusBar-PP.html).

Comment: The rest is just basics of the Haskell programming language - in this particular case defining a [lambda function](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html) by [pattern matching](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) and handling [lists](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/arrays.html): `ws:_` matches the input list and grabs its first element, `[ws]` reproduces it as a one-item list, and `\x -> … x …` defines this as an "anonymous" function matching the [type signature](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#type-signatures) figured out from the module's documentation.

Comment: I can't get this working at all - @pmf do you remember which version this applies to? I noticed some notes about xmobar working differently from version 0.1.7, wondering if that's it? I am getting e.g. `variable not in scope : spawnPipe`

Comment: `spawnPipe` resides in [XMonad.Util.Run](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Util-Run.html). Did you `import` it?

Comment: Thanks pmf, I finally got it to work as per your example here. One issue I noticed is that if I replace `desktopConfig` with some `myConfig`, it seems that xmobar is covered up by my windows (can only see it on empty workspace) do you happen to know why it could be ?

Comment: Look into `avoidStruts` in [XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Hooks-ManageDocks.html)